# How to control the over riding of Y-axis values in Chart.js when more entries inserted using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

Am new to PHP and working on a project where I need to show the tickets counts based on status in a bar graph. Its been working fine but, when more number of values inserted in a single day, the y-axis values are overriding on one another. Following is the code I've used for the bar graph and am using chart js for it.

**PHP CODE**

```
<div class="panel-body" id="chart_dist_tokens">
    <div class=" col-md-12">
        <div id="ticketsGraph" style="width:auto; height:275px;">
            <canvas id="barGraphForTickets"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var chartdata = {
   datasets: datasetValues,
   labels: formatDates
};

var myPieChart = new Chart(graphTarget,{
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata,
    options:{
        maintainAspectRatio:false,
        responsive:true,
        scales: {
           yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  stepSize: 1
              }
           }]
        }
    }
});
```

Following is the image of the graph am getting.

[image]

Is there any alternative to solve this issue using javascript or is it related to the misusing of graph code?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chart.js automatically calculates how many labels can be shown and hides labels accordingly. This is controlled by [`ticks.autoSkip`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) that has default value `true`.

If you explicitly define `yAxes.ticks.stepSize` however, `autoSkip` is ignored and a tick is shown for all matching steps.

**Solution 1**

The easiest solution is to remove `yAxis.ticks` from the options and let `autoSkip` manage tick generation.

**Solution 2**

You may also increase `stepSize` and choose whatever suits you.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    stepSize: 10
  }
}]
```

**Solution 3**

Another option would be to define the exact number of ticks to be show using `yAxes.ticks.maxTicksLimit`.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: 5
  }
}]
```